# Mesh with Mirror not working in 2.81

Tags: modifiers, mirror, snapping

I created an object using the mirror modifier around the global x and y axis, but since I started adding cylinders intersecting one of the mirror planes I already applied the modifier.

Now I want to edit the mesh, while still keeping symmetry in the y-direction, in which the object is still completely symmetrical. I read you can do this through Mesh --> Mirror --> Mirror Y, but when I click this and edit a vertex, nothing happens (neither for x nor z).

I am sure the geometry is exactly symmetrical as it was created with the *Mirror modifier* around the global axes. Strangely when I click *Snap to Symmetry* it says `0 already symmetrical, 0 pairs mirrored`.

Can anyone tell me what's up, or if there is an alternative for what I'm trying to achieve?

It is all one object and one mesh.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not saying hi or hello, I can't edit the post weirdly?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). *Mesh > Mirror* is not the best tool here. Why not just use the mirror modifier again? Just cut your object in half and add a Mirror modifier with Y axis.

Comment: Oh why didn't I think of that lol. It's pretty much my first project so I lack experience. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't worry about it, Blender can be overwhelming. Good luck with your project, looks good :).

Comment: Thank you! Can you guess what it is already?